# Unable to update the table

Tags: hibernate, command-prompt, sql-update

I have programmed a simple hibernate app which isn't updating the table. The following is my code. The table gets created but the it isn't updating

** Contact.java**

```
 public class Contact {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private long id;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setEmail(String string) {
    email = string;
}

public void setFirstName(String string) {
    firstName = string;
}

public void setLastName(String string) {
    lastName = string;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long l) {
    id = l;
}

}
```

**FirstExample.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class FirstExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = null;

    try {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        System.out.println("Inserting Record");
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setId(3);
        contact.setFirstName("Tausif");
        contact.setLastName("rahmathullah");
        contact.setEmail("t.r@vl.net");
        session.save(contact);
        System.out.println("updated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/simpHiber</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping resource="contact.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**contact.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="Contact" table="CONTACT">
  <id name="id" type="long" column="ID" >
  <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

 <property name="firstName">
 <column name="FIRSTNAME" />
 </property>
 <property name="lastName">
 <column name="LASTNAME"/>
 </property>
 <property name="email">
 <column name="EMAIL"/>
 </property>
</class>
```

Comment: Could you add some logging to your question

Comment: Any output from the program. Either in eclipse's console or a logfile. This is the most useful thing to look at when trying to resolve any issues

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Inserting Record
updated
Hibernate: insert into CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: The reason why you see this message is that your log4j configuration file(i.e. log4j.xml or log4j.properties) is NOT found in the classpath. Placing the log4j configuration file in the applications classpath should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using then `assigned` as id you need to set different ids every time you save.

```
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setId(3);//Change the id every time you insert.
    contact.setFirstName("Tausif");
    contact.setLastName("rahmathullah");
    contact.setEmail("t.r@vl.net");
    session.save(contact);
```

Now, **If you want update an entry instead of inserting it again use,**

```
    session.saveOrUpdate(contact);
```

This will fire an update query if the `id` exist in data base and will insert if it is not.

Comment: I got an error

     log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Inserting Record
Hibernate: select contact_.ID, contact_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_0_, contact_.LAST_NAME as LAST3_0_, contact_.EMAIL as EMAIL0_ fr
om CONTACT contact_ where contact_.ID=?
updated
Hibernate: insert into CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: that is not an error. Did you see the DB? How r u telling that no row is inserted?

Comment: yes. I checked the DB. it shows columns but empty set. Table is created but data not inserted.

Answer (score 0):

While using log4j in your application, sometimes you might encounter the following message:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(somePackageName.someClassName).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

The reason why you see this message is that your log4j configuration file(i.e. `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`) is NOT found in the classpath. Placing the log4j configuration file in the applications `classpath` should solve the issue.

One more thing this is not an error.It is an warning.Means it will create any problem while working.